# Is this an Eastern Banjo Frog?

Tags: species-identification, species

[[image: Close up of the frog's back[1]][image: frog in pot south coast NSW]

[image: frogs is about 50 - 60mm]
I found this little guy in my orchid on the upstairs balcony. I live at Sanctuary Point which is on the south coast NSW

Comment: You should probably add more precise size indications, as well as the country and the meaning of "NSW" (my first guess would have been "North-South-West", but it doesn't really make sense...).

Comment: Funny, after some guessing work, it seems that you are in New South Wales, a region of Australia. I first assumed that people forgetting to indicate their country were from the United States...

Comment: Ok....a few more details. I live in Australia, in the state of New South Wales on the east coast. The climate is warm temperate, the area is semi rural and my house is built on a 100 year flood plain. The frog was about 60 mm long and 45 mm wide with darker brown markings down it's back. Hope this info helps!

Comment: I've just added a photo which shows the frog's back.